# Drawing a Canvas circle slit into thirds

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, geometry

I think I'm missing something really basic here, I'm attempted to draw a circle split into thirds (think a pie chart as an example).

For this, I presumed I could draw three arcs with the following start/end values (in radians (rounded for brevity)):

```
arc 1: start 0, end: 2.09
arc 2: start 2.09, end: 4.18
arc 3: start 4.18 end, 6.28
```

I've console.logged the actual arcs I'm drawing to check the params, listed below:

```
arc(400,300,100,0,2.0943951023931953) 
arc(400,300,100,2.0943951023931953,4.1887902047863905) 
arc(400,300,100,4.1887902047863905,6.283185307179586)
```

Unfortunately when I do this I get the correct start and end points, but the arc doesn't seem to extend into the centre of the circle. As shown in the below image (ignore the centre circle)

[image]

Can anyone point me in the right direction to make the arcs draw the complete circle? it seems like they draw directly from the start to end radian in a straight line, but I was expecting them to go into the centre like a wedge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, scratch this, I see what I was doing.

Each arc was being drawn from the end point of the previous arc.

I had forgotten to `moveTo()` my centre point after each arc.

Comment: still the result was nice ! :-)

Comment: :p haha, thanks, if you can think of a sensible use for it! I couldn't!